# Is it really impossible to use hexagons for mixed-resolution cover?

Tags: tiling, tessellations

"To cover" and, more strictly, [**subpaving**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpaving) is a set of nonoverlapping "boxes" of **R⁺**. A subset *X* of **R²** can be approximated by two subpavings *X⁻* and *X⁺* such that
  *X⁻* ⊂ *X* ⊂ *X⁺*. 
Illustrating  bellow *X* as black line, *X⁻* the red cover and *X⁺* as the union of red and yellow.

[image]

In R², and a multi-scale [regular tesselations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#Regular_tilings), the "generic boxes" (also named "grid **cells**") can be quadrilateral shapes (square, rectangles or diamonds), triangular shapes, or hexagonal shapes.

In other words, the *subpaving* is a cover using a system of regular grids, where each cell can be split into a refined grid with same shapes. The *subpaving* is a  set without holes or overlaps.

Another important **restrictions**:

1. the area of the *parent-cell* is exactly the sum of the areas of all its *child cells*.
2. only one parent per cell.
3. (repeating subpaving definition) covering without holes or overlaps.
4. Finite satisfactory range of levels: need for 2, 3 or 4 hierarchical levels, not minus (2 as minimal) and no more for "satisfactory approximation" of *X* (by *X⁻* or *X⁺*).

... Seems *subpaving* is impossible with hexagons.
It is? 
**Is there a mathematical proof that it is impossible?**

---

### Motivation and illustration

The *cell* (and its *refiniment*) is a central concept of the **DGGS standard** ([ISO 19170-1](https://www.iso.org/standard/32588.html) or [OGC Topic 21](https://docs.ogc.org/as/20-040r3/20-040r3.html#cell)), and, as a [regular tile system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_tilings_by_convex_regular_polygons#Regular_tilings), the only possible shapes are triangular, hexagonal or quadrilateral.

[image]

... But, when the task is [*subpaving*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpaving), that is "to **cover** with multiple grid-scales and without holes or overlaps", seems it is impossible with hexagons.
It is? **Is there a mathematical proof that it is impossible?**

[image]

The map on the left (California) was covered by hexagons of four different sizes and the hexagons overlapped. The map on the right (Florida) was covered by quadrilateral shapes (diamonds) of four different sizes, with no holes and no overlaps.
Below is a detail in California, highlighting the holes (yellow) and overlaps (red) between the larger cells.

[image]

---

#### Notes

A cell-refinement process illustration, with hierarchical labeling schema and non-overlaping cells.

[image]

Bellow all are non-valid cell-refinement of hexagon:

[image]

The cases **a** and **b** are invalid by restrictions 1 and 2. The case **c** by restriction 3.

---

PS: about “to split a DGGS cell”, for an exact definition, see DGGS standards or [this animation](https://discreteglobal.wpengine.com/dggs-resolution/). About "Finite satisfatory limit" (restriction 4) see National and Global applications of DGGS, por example to solve the [Land Ownership](http://2015.index.okfn.org/dataset/land/) by approximating *X⁻* zones.

Comment: Perhaps an anwser at https://stackoverflow.com/a/759232/287948

Comment: What is the exact definition of what it means to “split” a cell? It can be defined so as to rule out example (c), but I don’t see how to do that without making your restrictions 1 and 2 redundant. The fact that you have these restrictions suggests to me that (c) should be valid.

Comment: Sorry @DavidK , I edited. The main restriction is in the definition phrase *"The subpaving is a set without holes or overlaps"*. In **c** we have triangular holes and overlaps.

Comment: I see no holes or overlaps in the subpaving. Note that the original paving is not part of the subpaving. You must look only at the subpaving itself with no other reference to say whether it has holes or overlaps.

Comment: Hi @DavidK, I edited again, see new illustration showing the hierarchical grid gaps at California's map.

Comment: With the *hexagons* we see *overlap* and with the *rectangles* wee se *overflow*. Did you try using *pentagons*, something halfway between *hexes* and *rects*?  The *hexes* seem to have different *orientations*, but the *rects* all have the same *orientation*.  If one degree of freedom is *size*, you should be able to increase the number of possible *hexes* or *rects* (different in size) and tile anything to near perfection.

Comment: Furthermore, the overlap with the hexes seem to cancel out with the areas the hexes can't reach (at the boundary. No such balancing act is visible with the rects, overflow (at the boundary) isn't balanced by areas the rects can't reach

Comment: Hi @AgentSmith,  the map border is not the point in the illustration. Sorry, I not have an illustration generator. The Florida map use *X⁺*, and the California map use a "balanced" (*X⁺* and  *X⁻*)... And perhaps the visual effect of "overflow" is because the hexagonal grid system have [*refinement ratio*](https://docs.ogc.org/as/20-040r3/20-040r3.html#refinement_ratio) 7, going faster to very-small cell. The quadrilateral grid system (at California map)   is using *refinement ratio* 4. PS: no problem with orientation.

Comment: @PeterKrauss, thank you for the clarification. Whether this is a point worthy of note or not you decide, but notice how a *part* (excluding triangles) of a rectangle is *still* a rectangle, but a *part* of a hexagon is a *trapezium* or a *triangle*. Isn't the impression that rectangles are *better* an illusion created by this *part* resembles the *whole* a la $\infty$ or fractals? You should be then allowed to use *equilateral triangles* or *trapeziums* and yet be able to say the tiling is *hexagonal*.

Comment: I think I may see where I misunderstood your purpose. What I said before assumed that you subpaved the entire map every time you needed smaller hexagons. In other words, you would make **all** hexagons smaller. If you keep some hexagons large and introduce smaller hexagons in the map, then indeed you will have gaps or overlaps as proved already in an answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidK, I edited adding restriction 4.

Comment: I think the important restriction is not the maximum number of hierarchical levels to be used in one tiling, but the **minimum** number of levels. If you are allowed to use only one level of the hierarchy then a hexagonal tiling is easy. But if you set a minimum of $2$ levels of hierarchy, the tiling is no longer possible, at least with regular hexagons.

Comment: @DavidK, thanks again, I edited replacing "limit" to "range" (from 2 to 4 levels).

Answer (score 5):

In a regular hexagon, all angles are $120$ degrees.  If you have two regular hexagons of different sizes share part of a side, you create an angle of $180 - 120 = 60$ degrees.  There is no way to pave that $60$ degree sector with a finite number of regular hexagons.